# No consigo configurar los virtualhost en apache

Tags: apache, apache2, virtualhost, vps

Estoy intentando hostear más de un sitio web en mi servidor debian 10 que es un VPS. Tras leer foros y foros no consigo terminar de conseguir hacer lo que quiero.

Tengo un dominio que es el primero que meti al apache con su .conf vamos a llamarle "dominio1.conf" y ahora al tratar de meterle más dominios todos me redireccionan al dominio 1. Pego aqui mis archivos para que los veais, el dominio 2 se llamara "dominio2.conf"

dominio1.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName dominio1.com
ServerAlias www.dominio1.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/dominio1
DirectoryIndex index.php

<Directory /var/www/dominio1/>
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =dominio1.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.dominio1.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

dominio2.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName dominio2.com
ServerAlias www.dominio2.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/dominio2
DirectoryIndex index.php

<Directory /var/www/dominio2/>
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =dominio2.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.dominio2.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Tengo los archivos de las webs en /var/www/

1. /var/www/dominio1
2. /var/www/dominio2

En ambos tengo un index.php diferente, pero siempre me muestra el del dominio1

Espero sus respuestas gracias.

Comment: has habilitado tus sitios `sudo a2ensite dominio1.conf`, el otro igual

Comment: Si ambos sitios se encuentran en el sites-available y sites-enabled a través de A2ensite.